# I am trying to write a code to eliminate unnecessary blank spaces in a document

Tags: python, text-formatting

I'm eliminating blank spaces from a text using python

```
test_text="Python is the                    best"
test_text=test_text.split(" ")
list(test_text)
print(test_text)
for i in test_text:
    if i == " ":
        test_text.remove(i)
print(test_text)
```

expected outcome=("python", "is", "the", "best") or "python is the best"

Comment: You should also post what text you are *actually* getting, so we can help diagnose it more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module:

```
import re

test_text="Python is the                    best"

output = re.sub(r'(\s){2,}', r'\1', test_text)
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
Python is the best
```

Edit (without re module):

```
test_text="Python is the                    best"
print(test_text.split())
```

Prints:

```
['Python', 'is', 'the', 'best']
```

Edit 2:

```
#to join it to one string:
print(' '.join(test_text.split()))
```

Prints:

```
Python is the best
```

Comment: okay thanks, but when i use print(test_text.split()) on the text i get ['Python', 'is', 'the', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'best', '']. And after using the snippet in my question I get ['Python', 'is', 'the', '', '', '', '', '', 'best', '']

Comment: @wizer_102 What Python version are you using? I'm using 3.6.8 and the text snipet you provided in your question.